# "&reg" being converted as "®"

Tags: php, html, html-entities, html-encode

i have been trying to get variables into my url, but at certein instances if i give a variable like "reg" it prints the "®" sign insted of reg

following is my code

```
$mainScript = new Main();
$Variables = $mainScript->FromProject($ID);
echo "print 1"."<br/>";
print_r($Variables);
echo "<br/>";

$urls = concat($Variables);
echo "print 2"."<br/>";
print_r($urls);
echo "<br/>";

foreach ($urls as $url){
echo "<PRE>&lt;img src='https://mytrackKit.test.com/"."rd?track=$ID&$url' &gt;&lt;/img&gt;</PRE>";
}
```

the echo

```
print 1
Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => a=SSS ) [ar] => Array ( [0] => ar=A [1] => ar=B [2] => ar=C [3] => ar=D ) [reg] => Array ( [0] => reg=1 [1] => reg=2 ) )
print 2
Array ( [0] => a=SSS&ar=A®=1 [1] => a=SSS&ar=A®=2 [2] => a=SSS&ar=B®=1 [3] => a=SSS&ar=B®=2 [4] => a=SSS&ar=C®=1 [5] => a=SSS&ar=C®=2 [6] => a=SSS&ar=D®=1 [7] => a=SSS&ar=D®=2 ) 

<img src='https://mytrackKit.test.com/rd?track=103&a=SSS&ar=A®=1'></img>
```

can anybody help me to get rid of this trademark R sign

Comment: If you dump variables for debug purposes then look at the page source, not at what the browser renders.

Comment: It is NOT just being displayed that way - the link has been changed / is misunderstood when clicked.

Answer (score 2):

`&reg;` is `html` `entity` character for Registered sign, you can escape it by escaping the `&` character using `&amp;` so what you need is `&amp;reg`.

Comment: Note: I have &reg_ in my parameters and it is being interpreted same as &reg;